# Keyword "this" into eventHandler function, runned into class

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm creating a Telegram bot and try to implement module-like architecture for it. So, for handling inline queries, I'm created that class:

```
class inlineVacationsHandler {
    constructor(bot){
        this.bot = bot;
        this.bot.on('inline_query',this.handler);
    }


    handler(msg){
       console.log(this.bot);
    }
}


var bot = new TelegramBot(config.token_dev, {polling: true});

var inline = new inlineVacationsHandler(bot);
```

But problem is, that I can't use class field "bot" in eventHandler, because in this case "this" don't point to inlineVacationsHandler class. So, how I can get "bot" object from hadler function? Thanks. I'm using Node.js and ES2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class inlineVacationsHandler {
    constructor(bot){
        this.bot = bot;
        this.bot.on('inline_query',this.handler.bind(this));
    }


    handler(msg){
       console.log(this.bot);
    }
}


var bot = new TelegramBot(config.token_dev, {polling: true});

var inline = new inlineVacationsHandler(bot);
```

> > Use this.bot.on('inline_query',this.handler.bind(this));

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for this silly question, totally forgot about bind function.